# Execute an if statement AND a block of code only if something is true, else do not execute the if statement, but execute the block of code

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a block of code which I do not want to wrap in a function. Let's call that block of code `block`. Here's what I want to do:

```
check = True
for loop:
    if (check):
        execute block
    else:
        if (another condition):
            execute block
```

I want to execute `block` anyway, but if a certain variable is False, I would like to place a check to limit the amount of times block is executed which is determined by `another condition`. I can copy and paste the block and have a code that resembles the pseudo-code above, however the `block` is more than 30 lines of code and I do not want to copy and paste it.

Let me know if I have clarified myself enough or I need to explain things a better.

Comment: @bierschi maybe they need access to variables that are part of the enclosing scope? Why must every question here be questioned?

Comment: Wait yea this is like what functions are for

Comment: @MarkRansom well the XY problem is a real thing

Comment: Is there any reason `if check or another_condition: execute block` isn't sufficient?

Comment: @MarkRansom I believe that's the solution to my problem, thank you! If you want, please go ahead and post it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, may somebody please explain to me what I did wrong to get the downvote?

Comment: @SuperStew they've already explicitly stated that they don't want to create a function, and having an explanation would just be noise unless it's somehow relevant to the answer. Assuming there's an XY problem is just rude unless you have some reason to believe it's so.

Comment: No need for me to post an answer if you're satisfied. Such a simple answer isn't likely to be useful to anybody but yourself.

Comment: @MarkRansom maybe it's relevant, maybe not. Won't know till we hear it. Since it is sort of uncommon to want to avoid functions, seems like there might be something there. That's reason enough for me to suspect an XY issue. If someone is so sensitive that they get offended at me asking questions, trying to help them with an issue, that's their own problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if cond1 and cond2: 
   # execute block

if cond1: 
    #statements
elif cond2:
    #other statements
```

I am not that sure what you totally  mean, but this is what I think you are trying to get?